# Sharepoint list with attachments in columns

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create list of products (with details like date of orders, etc). But I want to also add files for each product, like order document, leaflet, etc and of course I want to have possibility to filer/group by files. I try to create column with files in, but I fail. Maybe I can link somehow documents from Library to items in list?
Can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: please provide information about SharePoint version. Is it onPrem (with version?) or Online?

Answer (score 0):

I got the feeling the best solution to use here would be document sets. It is both for SP [onPrem](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-and-use-document-set-in-sharepoint-2013/) and [online](https://mikehatheway.com/2019/07/11/recent-sharepoint-updates-modern-document-sets/)

Basically a document set is like and item with metadata and a folder for files at the same time.

---

**Update1**

for SharePoint Online (onPrem the steps are very similar, just the look and feel is different)

- go to sitcollection features and activate document set feature.
- go to content types settings in sitecollection settings and create a new content type
- when creating content type make the content type inherit from document set content type
- then add some columns (like text fields, datetime pickers etc. whatever is needed, You may also have status column)
- after that in the document library You want to use the document set go to list settings and in advanced settings turn on content type management
- add the new document set content type (You may also add this ct as default one)
- when adding new item select the new content type. You will have the new form with all the defined columns, In the item You may add files like You would add them to the folder. Being in the item You may see the properties in the right property pane

I hope this solution is what You need :). I think it is the best OOTB solution that I can think of for Your problem.

---

**Update2**

please also check this [link](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/document-sets.cfm) for a similar step by step instructions but with screens.

Comment: I will check it, thanks, but needs clarification: every product have own data (serial number, description, status - example 'ready to shipment,  etc), but also documents. I want to have possibility to filter products by status - document set will do what I need? I'm afraid, that it will keep just files for products, but not products itself.

Comment: one more thing - I do that, but it's keeping me to creating new docx file for this document set, but I want to see this form, to fill in data, and upload correct file.

Comment: You may create a custom content type that inherits from document set. The content type may have this kind of columns You need.

Comment: I added a small update to maybe help You configure the document set and check this OOTB functionality. I hope it is good enough for Your problem :)